# Using aggregate function in a CTE query

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

The following query is working fine without ',MAX(Row)'

```
WITH QResult AS 
(SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Ad_Date DESC) AS Row,
    * 
 FROM [vw_ads]
) 
SELECT *, MAX(Row) 
FROM QResult
```

When `MAX(Row)` is added, SQL Server 2008 is throwing the following error :

> Column 'QResult.Row' is invalid in the select list because it is not
>   contained in either an aggregate function or the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to display.  Maybe provide some sample data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using an aggregate function like `SUM`, `COUNT` or `MAX`, and you want to also select other columns from your data, then you need to group your data by the other column(s) used in your query.

So you need to write something like:

```
WITH QResult AS 
(SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Ad_Date DESC) AS Row,
    * 
 FROM [vw_ads]
) 
SELECT Co1l, Col2, MAX(Row) 
FROM QResult
GROUP BY Col1, Col2
```

This also means you need to explicitly spell out the columns you want - a good idea in any case. You cannot use `*` in a `GROUP BY` clause.

**Update:** based on your comment, I guess what you really want is something like this:
(*see Update #2 - Martin Smith's suggestion is even better than my original idea here*)

```
WITH QResult AS 
(SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Ad_Date DESC) AS Row,
    * 
 FROM [vw_ads]
) 
SELECT 
    Co1l, Col2, 
    MaxRow = (SELECT MAX(Row) FROM QResult)
FROM QResult
```

This will give you the maximum value of `Row` from the CTE, the same value, for each row of your result set.

**Update #2:** Martin Smith's suggestion would be this:

```
WITH QResult AS 
(SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Ad_Date DESC) AS Row,
    * 
 FROM [vw_ads]
) 
SELECT 
    Co1l, Col2, 
    MAX(Row) OVER()
FROM QResult
```

and of course, this works, too - and even more efficient than my solution. Thanks, Martin!

Comment: thanks for your answer, i just want to get the count of the returned rows or the maximum value of 'Row' in the same query to avoid a separate call to the database or to improve performance quite a bit, your code in this case will return the associated value of 'Row' for each data row not the aggregate (the maximum value)!

Comment: @marc_s - You can just use `MAX(Row) OVER()`

Comment: @MartinSmith: excellent suggestion - thanks a heap! Updated my response once again :-)

Comment: @marc_s : thanks for answering this question your update1 is working fine, however in update2  MAX(Row) OVER() will throw the same exception again!

Comment: @Ala: works just fine for me - should be fine in SQL Server 2008. Are you using **exactly** the code I posted?

Comment: Oh sorry! using Over() will replace the group by, that is really great! Update2 is working very well, thank you so much Martin Smith and @marc_s

Answer (score 1):

You will need to decide why you are obtaining MAX(Row). Is it the max row by Ad_Date? Is the max row overall?

If you change it to:

```
WITH QResult AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Ad_Date DESC) AS Row,* FROM [vw_ads]) 
SELECT Ad_Date, MAX(Row) from QResult
GROUP BY Ad_Date
```

...that will return you the max row by Ad_Date which is what I'm assuming  you are looking for.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i just want to get the count of the returned rows or the maximum value of 'Row' in the same query to avoid a separate call to the database or to improve performance quite a bit, your code in this case will return the associated value of 'Row' for each data row not the aggregate (the maximum value)!